# Python wb writes to memory address instead of path

Tags: python

For some reason this codes saves the file to a memory address instead of the specified path Oo, anyone any ideas on how to solve this :)

```
def save_csv(self, path, trend_name):
    fileName = "~/Videos" + "data" + ".csv"
    with open(fileName, mode='wb') as f:
        f.write(self.decode_data.encode('utf8'))
```

Here's the Pudb output:

```
Return: NoneType
absolute_import: instance
build_opener: <function build_opener at 0xb6965d14>
CookieJar: cookielib.CookieJar
copy: <module 'copy' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.pyc'>
csv: <module 'csv' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/csv.pyc'>
datetime: <type 'datetime.datetime'>
expanduser: <function expanduser at 0xb750be2c>
HTTPCookieProcessor: urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor
json: <module 'json' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.pyc'>
logging: <module 'logging' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.pyc'>
open: <built-in function open>
parse_data: <function parse_data at 0xb6a0c144>
print_function: instance
pyGTrends: <class '__main__.pyGTrends'>
quote: <function quote at 0xb6befed4>
re: <module 're' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/re.pyc'>
requests: <module 'requests' from '/home/lk/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.pyc'>
StringIO: <built-in function StringIO>
sys: <module 'sys' (built-in)>
unicode_literals: instance
urlencode: <function urlencode at 0xb6beff44>
UserAgent: <class 'fake_useragent.fake.UserAgent'>
```

Comment: only shell automatically resolve ~, imo.

Comment: "A memory address"...? How do you come to that conclusion?

Comment: I used the pudb debugger

Comment: You used pudb *and saw what?*

Comment: Where does that say anything about memory?

Comment: It used to, now it doesn't anymore...

Comment: What does pudb say about using _only_ the example in my answer? You have something wrong in your code.

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned in the comments, you should use the path directly like this:

```
fileName = "home/<username>/Videos/" + "data" + ".csv"
```

as only bash expands `~` to full `home/<username>` path.

Also, it uses memory, but then you don't know where does it write to i.e. `~/Videos`. So yeah, it's saved, but not in the place you want it to.

Similar may be:

```
with open('file.txt', 'wb')
```

Do you know where it'll save? In the folder you open the interpreter from, not in the folder where your `main.py` is. And in this way you may think the file "isn't saved", but actually it is. Try to look to the interpreter folder if there is a folder `~` and file `Videos...` or whole file named `~/Videos...`

Also `expanduser()` will solve this for you as another answer mentions + to make sure you have the correct path and you didn't leave something out, use [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).

Example:

```
from os.path import join
with open(join('/home/<username>', 'Videos', 'data.csv'), mode='wb') as f:
    f.write('test')
```

Comment: Changed it to

fileName = "/home/lk/Videos" + "debt" + ".csv"

Still nothing :/

Comment: @LKLAW: I hop you realize that the result of that will be `"/home/lk/Videosdebt.CSV"`, not `"/home/lk/Videos/debt.CSV"`.

Comment: Already was writing that you need slashes everywhere if you want the correct path, use `os.path.join()` and don't bother with those

Comment: Or just write it out in one string.

Comment: With and without the / at the end of path it doesn't make any difference

Comment: Try it in simple console and it'll work. Maybe you didn't call the function or something.

Comment: @LKLAW: I mentioned no slash at the *end*.  It's the one in the middle I'm worried about.  I assume that Videos is a directory, not part of the file name.

Comment: @LKLAW `os.path.join('/home/<user>', 'Videos', 'data.csv')`

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr doesn't work, argh this is so annoying --"

Comment: @LKLAW did you call that example from console?

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr You mean if I ran it in the terminal ?

Comment: *"Do you know where it'll save? In the interpreter folder, not in the folder where your main.py is"* This is just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It is the shell that converts `~` to the home path.  Python does, however, have its own function for that, [`os.path.expanduser()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser):

```
from os.path import expanduser

def save_csv(self, path, trend_name):
    fileName = expanduser("~/Videos/data.csv")
    with open(fileName, "wb") as f:
        f.write(self.decode_data.encode('utf8'))
```

Comment: Tried it, it doesn't save it as well :'(

Comment: Are you sure that the function is being called?  Try adding a `print` statement to the beginning of the function.